# php api remove duplicate values from different keys json

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have a php script that is outputting a json response that looks something like this ( if it matters, the response below was outputted by a test ajax call ) ---

```
{
  "type": "the type",
  "typesm": "type of",
  "entries": [
    {
      "title": "title one",
      "body": "Original text",
      "image": "image 1 url",
      "time": "1558532690",
      "meta": {
        "mainColor": "#100a0e",
        "adSpace": null
      }
    },
    {
      "title": "title two",
      "body": "Original text",
      "image": "image 1 url",
      "time": "1558515409",
      "meta": {
        "mainColor": "#100a0e",
        "adSpace": null
      }
    },
```

So in my `entries` I have duplicate values for `body` and `image`, but everything else seems fine.

In my script I am outputting my values like this for example -

```
$entries = $result->entries;

foreach ($entries as $ent){
echo $ent->image;
echo $ent->title;
echo $ent->body;
}
```

My problem is I dont want to output any entries with duplicate data, regardless if the title is different. If the image and body is a duplicate as another entry then I want to skip over it.

How can I achieve this?

**EDIT**

Exact JSON response structure from php print_r -

```
stdClass Object
(
    [type] => game
    [typesm] => br
    [entries] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [title] => Hang Time Bundle
                    [body] => Score big when you cop the Hang Time Bundle, available now in the Item Shop. Unlock new Styles with Creative Mode Challenges.
                    [image] => https://imageurl.jpeg
                    [time] => 1558532690
                    [meta] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [mainColor] => #100a0e
                            [adSpace] => 
                        )

                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [title] => Hang Time Set
                    [body] => Score big when you cop the Hang Time Bundle, available now in the Item Shop. Unlock new Styles with Creative Mode Challenges.
                    [image] => https://imageurl.jpeg
                    [time] => 1558515409
                    [meta] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [mainColor] => #100a0e
                            [adSpace] => 
                        )

                )
```

Comment: Your image values are not the same in the array you post. Should it be?

Comment: @Andreas that was a mistake. i updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array_column to make the entries array associative and remove the duplicates.

```
$json = 'json string';
$arr = json_decode($json, true);
$arr['entries'] = array_column($arr['entries'], null, 'body');


foreach ($arr['entries'] as $ent){
    echo $ent['image'];
    echo $ent['title'];
    echo $ent['body'];
}
```

This way, when you loop to output you only have unique values.

You can also use array_unique but making the array associative can be beneficial in other ways.

---

If you want to delete duplicates according to both image and body then loop the array and make a compound associative keys.

```
$json = 'json string';
$arr = json_decode($json, true);
foreach($arr['entries'] as $e){
    $ent[$e['body'] . " " . $e['image']] = $e;
}
```

$ent is now the new array with unique values of 'entries'

```
foreach ($ent as $e){
    echo $e['image'];
    echo $e['title'];
    echo $e['body'];
}
```

Comment: I tried both your examples and wasnt able to output anything anymore

Comment: There is no output included in my answers. I figured you knew how to do that.

Comment: Included output as in your question.

Comment: Both codes work fine **with a correct json**. I hope you didn't expect that you posted was going to work? https://3v4l.org/hdP0h

Comment: I still cant get it to work. I updated my question with the response in php from print_r

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193783/discussion-between-andreas-and-rich).

Comment: The first two words means you didn't use my code. `stdClass Object` with json_decode(..., **true**) you get an array

Comment: aha I missed the `true` on the decode. one last question, if i need to modify it so it removes entries only based on body and not image, how can I?

Comment: Based on only body is above the line, the array_column part